# Some documents not showing in All Documents View

Tags: view

I have a problem with the All Documents view - the "(more items...)" link at the bottom of the list of documents is not allowing all the documetns to be viewed on one page. I know the documents are in the folder as the explorer view shows them. Please can anyone let me know if there is a setting I have missed?

Answer (score 2):

You can customize the `All Documents` view to show any number of documents you specific using the `Item Limit` setting. I believe the maximum number of items that a library can display is 5,000 (unless this setting is increased in Central Administration).

On the Ribbon in your library, click `Library > Modify View` to bring up the `Edit View` page. Scroll down and under the `Item Limit` setting, enter how many documents to display under the `Number of items to display`.

If you're using a web part to display the `All Documents` view of your library, you'll need to edit the web part properties and select the `All Documents` view again under the `Selected View` property. Also, you can customize this view directly in the web part by clicking `Edit the current view` in the web part properties. However, if you do this, this customized view will only be available for that particular web part.